# Is there a macro to convert an Error to Panic?

Tags: error-handling, macros, rust, panic

Is there a macro that will convert an error into a panic, similar to the `try` macro? Do I need to define my own?

For example I'd like to panic if a unit test can't open a file. My current workaround is this:

```
macro_rules! tryfail {
    ($expr:expr) => (match $expr {
        result::Result::Ok(val) => val,
        result::Result::Err(_) => panic!(stringify!($expr))
    })
}

#[test]
fn foo() {
    let c = tryfail!(File::open(...));
}
```

Comment: I think the expect function is what you are looking for although it isn't a macro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what the methods [`Result::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) and [`Result::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) do.

I know you are asking for a macro, but I think your use case can be fulfilled with the `unwrap` method:

```
#[test]
fn foo() {
    let c = File::open(...).unwrap();
    // vs
    let c = tryfail!(File::open(...));
}
```

Note that in code that is not test, it's more [idiomatic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html#a-brief-interlude-unwrapping-isnt-evil) to use `expect`.

If you really want a macro, you can write one using `unwrap`.

Comment: Note that [`Option::expect`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.expect) and [`Option::unwrap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) also exist.